# MySQL Уникальный индекс по двум полям независимо от порядка

Tags: mysql, sql, индексы

Имеется таблица диалогов пользователей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для предотвращения появления дубликатов хочу использовать уникальный индекс по двум полям (user1_id, user2_id), но необходим уникальный индекс независимо от порядка, т.е. например, если брать первый диалог с идентификатором 4, то дубликатом будет считаться не только запись "1, 9" , но и "9, 1". Такое вообще возможно сделать с помощью индексов? Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11414976/5741205

Comment: Generated column + уникальный индекс по нему.

Comment: @Akina тогда получится, что 1+9 и 5+5 будут считаться дубликатами, или я не правильно понимаю? MaxU дал ссылку, там решение на аналогичный вопрос, но там все на английском, жаль я ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Generated column expression не ограничивается сложением двух значений. Например, `CONCAT_WS(CHAR(0), LEAST(x1,x2), GREATEST(x1,x2))` лишён описанного недостатка...

Comment: @Akina спасибо, теперь до меня дошло